# Pandas groupby date month and count items within months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
STYLE | INVOICE_DATE2
A     | 2017-01-03
B     | 2017-01-03
C     | 2017-01-03
A     | 2017-02-03
A     | 2017-01-03
B     | 2017-02-03
B     | 2017-01-03
```

I'm trying to group them by month and count itself within month, result must like this:

```
Month | Item | Count
1     | A    | 2
      | B    | 2
      | C    | 1
2     | A    | 1
      | B    | 1
```

I have tried this:

```
lastyear_df.groupby([(df['INVOICE_DATE2']).dt.month, df['STYLE']])['STYLE'].count()
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close, need `size` if want count `NaN`s:

```
d = {'INVOICE_DATE2':'Month','STYLE':'Item'}
df = (df.groupby([df['INVOICE_DATE2'].dt.month, 'STYLE'])
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='Count')
       .rename(columns=d))
print (df)
   Month Item  Count
0      1    A      2
1      1    B      2
2      1    C      1
3      2    A      1
4      2    B      1
```

Or `count` for `count` only no `NaN`s:

```
d = {'INVOICE_DATE2':'Month','STYLE':'Item'}
df = (df.groupby([df['INVOICE_DATE2'].dt.month, 'STYLE'])['STYLE']
       .count()
       .reset_index(name='Count')
       .rename(columns=d))
print (df)
   Month Item  Count
0      1    A      2
1      1    B      2
2      1    C      1
3      2    A      1
4      2    B      1
```

Last if need only one unique value in first column:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].mask(df.duplicated('Month'),'')
print (df)
  Month Item  Count
0     1    A      2
1          B      2
2          C      1
3     2    A      1
4          B      1
```

Comment: jezrael thank, it works, I'm waiting for approve, by the way, can we order within months? thanks

Comment: if i make: sort_values(by=['Count'], ascending=False) it breaks month column

Comment: I think you need `df.sort_values(by=['Month','Count'], ascending=[True,False])` ?

Comment: No it doesn't work, I meant order counts from biggest to lowest for every month

Comment: For me it working nice `df = df.sort_values(by=['Month','Count'], ascending=[True,False])`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner...

```
ans = df.groupby([df.INVOICE_DATE2.apply(lambda x: x.month), 'STYLE']).count()
```

Here is the output

```
In [21]: ans
Out[21]:
                     INVOICE_DATE2
INVOICE_DATE2 STYLE
1             A                  2
              B                  2
              C                  1
2             A                  1
              B                  1
```

NOTE: That at this point you have a hierarchical index, which you can flatten by using `reset_index`

```
ans = ans.reset_index(1)
              STYLE  INVOICE_DATE2
INVOICE_DATE2
1                 A              2
1                 B              2
1                 C              1
2                 A              1
2                 B              1
```

You can now change the column and index names if you like:

```
ans.index.name = 'MONTH'
ans.columns = ['ITEM', 'COUNT']
```